# OrientDb - Get node and all of its relations

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Can I do one query to achieve vertex and all of his edges (including the other vertexes)?

now I'm doing multiple queries to achieve it:

For getting the vertex:

```
select from V where entity_name = 'SomeEntity'
```

Then going over each edge and select it:

```
select from #EDGE@rid // Multiple in the number of edges for this node
```

And at the end going over the edges and getting all other vertexes (except the original)

```
select from #VERTEX@rid // Multiple in the number of vertexes in the edges
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following to get all Vertexes and Edges in the required depth from my Vertex:

```
TRAVERSE inE(), outE(), inV(), outV() 
FROM (select from V where entity_name = 'SomeEntity') 
WHILE $depth <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,in(),out() FROM V WHERE entity_name = 'SomeEntity'
```

Comment: This query also returns the ids of the edges, not a full instance of those edges, I think TRAVERSE is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

An observation; the answer by Dor Cohen works if the structure is a tree. However, if   it is a cyclical graph, the last edge on the longest path is missed, due to the node visit strategy of not visiting the node which has been visited. The solution that worked for me is as below:

TRAVERSE out(), outE() FROM #22:1 WHILE $depth <= 4

The query traverses all the nodes with are deemed progressively out of the vertex and then the edges which are progressively out from all the vertices.

The output looks like:

[image]

The structure of the graph:

[image]

On the other hand if the above style of query is used (though I am not looking for in vertex or edge), the output is:

[image]

The edge from #22:4 to #23:1 is missed (as a record), as it falls on the longer path. The reference of the missed edge (#28:2) is available on both the above records though.